# Automatic reboot and revert grub config on boot failure?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, reboot

I have a working RHEL in /dev/sda1 and a newly constructed Ubuntu Lucid in /dev/sda2. I'm going to edit the grub config and reboot the server into the new Ubuntu. However, I'm not 100% sure that the new distro can boot. And since my only way to access the server is via SSH, I need the network to be up too.

How can I configure Grub and Ubuntu so that if the server fails to boot, it will automatically reboot into the old RHEL?

Currently using GRUB 0.93, but I can upgrade it if needed.

---

**Update:**
In the end, no boot failure occured. But without the insurance from this, I wouldn't have attempted https://serverfault.com/questions/208128/how-to-remotely-install-linux-via-ssh =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if 0.93 can do it, but 0.97 is capable of [booting once-only](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Booting-once_002donly.html#Booting-once_002donly). Grab the grub SRPM from Fedora if need be and rebuild it.

You'll also need to tell your other install to [reboot on panic](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/reboot-linux-box-after-a-kernel-panic.html) (the `panic` kernel parameter is what you need to set in the bootloader configuration).

Answer (score 1):

While 0.93 does not support that option from 0.97, fortunately you can do `savedefault --default=1 --once` in the grub batch mode. See http://www.linux-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/2928-grub-single-boot-and-kernel-panic-reboot/ for details

In addition to that, I've put a auto-reboot script in `/etc/cron.d` so that in case the network doesn't work in the new system, I can still get back to the working system.